# Using django-profiles with Django 1.5

Tags: django, django-1.4, django-1.5, django-profiles

I am working again on a Django 1.4 project which I am trying to get working with 1.5. I was using the module [`django-profiles`](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-profiles), unfortunately the module is using Django generic views (`list_detail` particularly) and [they aren't supported anymore in 1.5 IIRC](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-profiles/issue/18/no-module-named-list_detail).

Is there a known workaround for this (besides quitting `django-profiles`) ?

Thanks,

Comment: Waiting for approval (pull request): *[Replaced `profile_list` view with a class-based view. This will change the requirement to django >=1.4 and require a MAJOR version bump.](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-profiles/pull-request/6/replaced-profile_list-view-with-a-class/diff)* So I guess a new release is coming up which will solve your issue.

Comment: I'm quite new to the pull request thing (and yet already liking the concept) didn't see what you linked. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Using an alternative package may be the better option.

James Bennett, the author, has said unless someone wants to take it over, he intends to let it die.

http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2013/aug/26/catching/

> django-profiles, which used to be django-registration’s favorite companion app, is effectively dead. The use case for it is increasingly irrelevant (you no longer need to use the cumbersome user-profile system, since you can just as easily build your own custom user model), and like django-registration, trying to support everything people now want from an app like that is probably not going to be pretty. If someone wants to take it over, they’re welcome to give it a try, but otherwise I intend to simply let it die.

There's plenty of alternatives, which are being actively maintained. I'm trying django-userena, which combines the functionality offered by django-profiles and django-registration (another of James Bennett's project which he intends to hand off or let die)